# app.UseMvc routes in asp.net doesn't exists

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm learning asp.net and I have a issue using routes in the startup file.
I need to change the url to do something like this

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
routes.MapRoute(
name: "pagination",
template: "Products/Page{productPage}",
defaults: new { Controller = "Product", action = "List" });
```

But it said template parameter does not exists. I'm using Endpoints so how to do it with endpoints?

My actual code looks like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Product}/{action=List}/{id?}");

    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I suggest an easier way by declaring your route above the action itself.

```
[Route("Products/Page/{productPage?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Products(string productPage) {
    return View();
}
```